# ngFor is not showing the items in html? Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is really bothering me. I'm trying to display an array in angular 2/4. I think there's a mistake in Angular. the html, service, or component part, because my node back end works as it should. My html looks like this.

```
<div class = "container">

<li *ngFor = "let customer of customers">
    <div class = "col md-6">
            {{ customer.firstName }}
    </div>
</li>
<div *ngFor = "let customer of customers">
    <div class = "col md-6">
            {{ customer.lastName }}
    </div>
</div>
```

My service is this

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

//retreiving custmers
getCustomers(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/api/customers')
    .map(res => res.json());
}
}
```

My component is this

```
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {

customers: Customer[];
customer: Customer;
firstName: string;
lastName: string;

//initialize customer service   
constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

//initiated once component is loaded
ngOnInit() {

this.customerService.getCustomers()
    .subscribe( customer => 
        this.customer = customer);


 }
```

Comment: Just on the basis of the names, `getCustomers().subscribe(customer => ...` seems fishy. It's a bad idea to define the same name in the template as in the class, too. Also you should look in the console to see what errors you're getting so you can give a [mcve].

Comment: In case that was too obtuse for you, you have two properties in your class,  `customer` and `customers` which are defined as they sound being 'singular' and 'list' respectively. Note how your service method subscription is assigning to the 'singular' one. That's just a starting point hint, but the general message is that you probably really have some debugging to do "before" running off and posting a question to StackOverflow. That's what would be preferred.

Comment: John thank you. Neil your obtuse. you both pointed me in the right direction. It should have been this.customers. This fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo , change `customer` to be `customers`

```
this.customerService.getCustomers()
    .subscribe( customers => {

        this.customers = customers

      });

 }
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: *"You have a typo"* - then close as typographical error, as this is no use to anyone else.